# RUBY: If/Else statement that creates a loop

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement

I am looking for the proper way to do this in Ruby.  I want to create an if/else statement that will keep looping until it finds the right answer.  Example:

```
puts "Guess a number",prompt
$stdin.gets.chomp = x
if x == 5
   puts "correct
else
    # loop back to beginning and start over
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `while` statement to loop, if guess the number, then break, like this:

```
while true
  puts "Guess a number:"
  if gets.chomp.to_i == 5
     puts "correct"
     break
  end
  puts "guessed wrong, please try again!"
end
```

or use `until` statement:

```
puts "Guess a number:"
until gets.chomp.to_i == 5 do
  puts "guessed wrong, please try again!"
end

puts "correct"
```

as @izaban said, `loop...do` also can work:

```
loop do
  puts "Guess a number:"
  if gets.chomp.to_i == 5
     puts "correct"
     break
  end
  puts "guessed wrong, please try again!"
end
```

Comment: You could also use `loop do` instead of `while true`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without using break:

```
guess = 0
first_run_through = true

until guess == 5
  puts 'guessed wrong, please try again!' unless first_run_through
  first_run_through = false
  puts 'Guess a number'
  guess = gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts 'correct'
```